# AWS S3 SLA Info

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am planning to move to AWS S3 to store files. Though I been through the S3 FAQs but still I want to be sure about few more things specifically about S3 mentioned below -

1.How S3 recovers the data if some bucket is lost ? Does it keep the data back-up as well ?

2.Though my application will not be using S3 exhaustively, but how about if S3 gets down(availability issues handling by S3) ?

Thanks.

Comment: S3's been around for a long time now (10+ years). S3 has had [very] few partial outages during that time. If you are less than five nines HA, your code/servers are going down MUCH more than S3 ever has.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your data to retain at most, you can enable versioning and cross version replicate so you have higher chance to get to your data even if a zone gets down. You can refer to this blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/ for more information about this feature
2. you can refer to https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/ about SLA consideration